# Limit subcategories of parent category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying only 6 sub categories of a Parent Category, this is the code I am using

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$param_type = 'category__in';
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('Makeup');
$term_args=array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'child_of' => $cat_id,
'limit' => 6 );
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);

if ($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<h4><?php echo $term->name;?></h4>
```

> Here results are coming limit less.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I limited the categories using    'number' => 6;